# How to create a command that will stop multiple Discord bot functions from working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Look, I have a bot that changes the color of a video. If you write the !cc74 command, the bot will run the following functions: ccrole1, ccrole2, ccrole3, that is, three roles will change their color endlessly. But I need to create a command named: !stopccrole which stops the ccrole1, ccrole2, ccrole3 functions and the roles stop changing their color. Please write your own code on how to do this.

Code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(1122088739678724166)
async def stopccrole(ctx):
#help me here, I need the ccrole1, ccrole2, ccrole3 functions to stop working and the color of the roles to stop changing when I enter this command.

#runs three functions at once
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(1122088739678724166)
async def cc74(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="CCrole1 тя работает <:Kris74icon:1123156576325353522>", color=0x7000ff)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await asyncio.gather(ccrole1(ctx), ccrole2(ctx), ccrole3(ctx))

#CCrole1
@client.event
async def ccrole1(ctx):
  colours = [0x264653, 0x2a9d8f, 0xe9c46a, 0xf4a261, 0xe76f51]
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1123145522790809710)
  x = 0
  while True:
    x = (x + 1) % 5
    await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colours[x]))
    await asyncio.sleep(6)

#CCrole2
@client.event
async def ccrole2(ctx):
  colours = [0x9b5de5, 0xf15bb5, 0xfee440, 0x00bbf9, 0x00f5d4]
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1123145643679023124)
  x = 0
  while True:
    x = (x + 1) % 5
    await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colours[x]))
    await asyncio.sleep(6)

#CCrole3
@client.event
async def ccrole3(ctx):
  colours = [0xffd60a, 0xffc300, 0x003566, 0x001d3d, 0x000814]
  role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1123145712947961858)
  x = 0
  while True:
    x = (x + 1) % 5
    await role.edit(colour=discord.Colour(colours[x]))
    await asyncio.sleep(6)
```

I have tried many things, but I hope to get an answer